# exponent such that expectation equals 1

Tags: probability, reference-request, random-variables, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

For some random variables $X>0$ supported on the real positive half line $(0,\infty)$ there is a real number $\alpha>0$ such that the expected value $\mathbb E[X^\alpha]$ equals $1$. Is there a name for the quantity $\inf \{ \alpha >0: \mathbb E[X^\alpha]=1\}$?

Comment: Which distribution, mean, and standard deviation are you using?

Comment: @TymaGaidash For a given (real) random variable $X$ and its probability distribution $\mathbb P(X\in \cdot)$ there are several prominent statistics such as "mean", "standard deviation", etc. -- so I was wondering if $\inf \{ \alpha>0: \mathbb E[X^\alpha]=1\}$ has a name, too. (reference-request)